# UserControl content is empty when trying to use ContentPresenter inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, inheritance, user-controls, contentpresenter

I have a main abstract code-only class BaseImpostorButton, inheriting UserControl. I have a child class ClickableImageButton with xaml and code-behind.

I'm using the following style with ControlTemplate :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ClickableImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ClickableImageButton}">
                <StackPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>                
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When using in a ListView as raw ListViewItem, my ClickableImageButton shows correctly.

BUT: when using it in a listview with ItemTemplate DataTemplate, the ClickableImageButton is no longer shown... as if the Content was empty when inside a DataTemplate.

The solution i found was to write a DependencyProperty ButtonContent on BaseImpostorButton and set it explicitly in xaml.

But can someone explain this issue ?

EDIT: Here are the 2 different xaml
The one that is correctly showing the underlying image (ClickableImage is an Image)

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="ListViewSections" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sections}" Background="{x:Null}" SizeChanged="ListViewSections_SizeChanged">                    
            <ListViewItem>
<Grid MaxWidth="600">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=Titre}" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <local:ClickableImageButton Grid.Row="1" Tag="{Binding Path=Id}" Grid.Column="0" ImpostorClick="Image_Click" Margin="10">
                            <local:ClickableImageButton.Content>
                                <local:ClickableImage Source="Content/tada.png" />
                            </local:ClickableImageButton.Content>
                        </local:ClickableImageButton>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Texte}" Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>                                       
            </ListViewItem>                
        </ListView>
```

And the one that's not working

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="ListViewSections" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sections}" Background="{x:Null}" SizeChanged="ListViewSections_SizeChanged">                    
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MaxWidth="600">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=Titre}" Margin="5,0,5,0" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <local:ClickableImageButton Grid.Row="1" Tag="{Binding Path=Id}" Grid.Column="0" ImpostorClick="Image_Click" Margin="10">
                            <local:ClickableImageButton.Content>
                                <local:ClickableImage Source="Content/tada.png" />
                            </local:ClickableImageButton.Content>
                        </local:ClickableImageButton>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Texte}" Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>                
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Why are you deriving from user control, if you don't use it? I would advise to derive directly from ContentControl. And the ContentPresenter inside the Template of a Controlcontrol, automatically takes Templatebindings for Content, ContentTemplate, and ContentTemplateSelector ... thus <ContentPresenter /> should be suffice.

Comment: Deriving the base abstract class from ContentControl doesn't change anything. And UserControl IS a ContentControl

Comment: Did you write `<local:ClickableImageButton Content="{Binding}" ... />` in your DataTemplate?

Comment: Not exactly : `<local:ClickableImageButton> <local:ClickableImageButton.Content><local:ClickableImage Source="{Binding Path=Image.Source}" /></local:ClickableImageButton.Content></local:ClickableImageButton>`

Comment: ClickableImage is a code-only class that i construct from XML data. This code works when in the scope of a ListViewItem, but not i the scope of an ItemTemplate/DataTemplate

Comment: You should perhaps edit your question and add the relevant XAML parts for both cases, inside ListViewItems and in a DataTemplate.

Comment: Besides my comment, you do know that you can't use templates with UserControls, don't you? See the remarks of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @dowhilefor: You absolutely right ! MDSN says
`Before deriving from UserControl, consider that your control will not support templates.`
But this is somewhat weird... It implies that UserControl doesn't have the same behavior than its base class...

Comment: @LoulG Thats what i meant with "Why are you deriving from user control, if you don't use it" It has a template, but a fixed template, which you fill by using the xaml usually generated by the IDE. You weren't using that, instead deriving from ContentControl and setting the DefaultStyleKey should be suffice.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Now i understand your meaning. I can't test changes for now, but i will test asap.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Hi. Regarding the first code part above, i just emptyed the content presenter `<ContentPresenter />`. I also derived my BaseImpostorButton from ContentControl instead of UserControl. The control still not show when used inside a template...

Comment: @dowhilefor: and i also set the BaseImpostorButton ctor to static and put `FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BaseImpostorButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BaseImpostorButton)));`

Comment: @LoulG. please use snoop to exactly check what is missing from your visual tree. Check the output for any warnings or errors. Where did you place your default style? In a resource xaml? In the app.xaml? In the generic.xaml? Make sure it doesn't have a name. Make sure that the size won't compute to (0, 0) depending on the content and the used layouter, again try snoop to check for that. Deriving from ContentControl, setting the DefaultStyleKey, creating a proper default style(without a name) inside the generic.xaml or app.xaml, works for me.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Actually, the style is in an external dictionary, whith only TargetType set to ClickableImageButton. Actually it's working too when deriving from ContentControl, setting the DefaultStyleKey. But it's not the problem. This only work if default Control content is absolutely empty.

Comment: Does someone have an explanation to this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

So finally i get it to work. That wasn't due to the fact that i was deriving from UserControl.

So i kept deriving BaseImpostorButton from UserControl, i emptyed the ContentPresenter in the ControlTemplate (`<ContentPresenter />`).

I didn't have to set the DefaultStyleKey.

I just had to remove any content from the child class xaml file. Indeed, when i created my child UserControl, i didn't removed the default content added, that is `<Grid />`. Removing this just solved all my problems.

Looks like the default Content is not overriden when we try to set it from a templated context, but only when set from a non templated context.

ie Former code:

```
<sk:BaseImpostorButton x:Class="Compteur_3D.ClickableImageButton"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid/>
</sk:BaseImpostorButton>
```

revised code:

```
<sk:BaseImpostorButton x:Class="Compteur_3D.ClickableImageButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
</sk:BaseImpostorButton>
```

Edit: At runtime, my ClickableImageButton element has the right content (ie ClickableImage) when the `<Grid />` is removed. BUT when `<Grid />` is not removed, my ClickableImageButton has the empty Grid as content... As if this `<Grid />` was not overriden when setting the content in:

```
<local:ClickableImageButton ImpostorClick="Image_Click" Margin="10">
                            <local:ClickableImageButton.Content>
                                <local:ClickableImage Source="{Binding Path=Image.Source}" />
                            </local:ClickableImageButton.Content>
                        </local:ClickableImageButton>
```

Edit: Target Framework 4 Client Profile